# REGEX to select CSS Classes names from file

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation, regex-group

I need to select all classes names in a css file, I am just new at it, also if someone can advice some good online tutorials for regex is appreciated.

Regex will be used in JavaScript

I came with this which works for simple classes:
`/(?<=\.).+?(?=\{)/g`

```
.className { 
}
```

the above regex returned this: `className`

now I need to add for this too:

```
tagName1 {
}

#tagName2 {
}

.tagName3:hover {
}

.tagName4:anything {
}
```

> ```
> should result in:
> tagname1
> tagname2
> tagname3
> tagname4
> ```

So how to select the above ones?

Comment: Do you have any examples of what should __not__ match? Because from the only information you provided, this would work: [`(?<=\.|^|#)\w+(?=\s?{)`](https://regex101.com/r/Chh7qX/1). You should also [edit] your question and include the language you are using.

Comment: I don't understand the last two examples. `className` is not a class name, it's a tag name. And `#className` is an ID, not a class name. What about more complex CSS selectors, like `.classname:hover`?

Comment: @Barmar, great, yes, I need to select tag names as well, and remove the :hover part or :(something) part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that, we would want to design an expression similar to,

```
([^:#\s.]+)(?:.*?)?\s*({[^}]*?})
```

where in this capturing group,

```
([^:#\s.]+)
```

we would deselect some chars such as `.`, `#` and space, and we'd collect our desired data.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LFJAuz/1)

Comment: Great, also, to mark as correct answer, I just forgot to ask to add this:  in case the class is: .className:hover you need to remove the :hover part, or any :something part

Comment: Looks good, also, can you please add an extra one for selecting as well the content of the class? everything inside the { xxxx } as well as the classnames and the { ?  this is my last request haha

Answer (score 1):

I'd use:

```
 ^[.#]?(\w+)(?=(?::\w+)?\s*{)
```

The wanted name is in group #1

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LFJAuz/3) with javascript regex flavour.